# Display problems on Linux product

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm working on a Router under linux OPENWRT. Sometimes it happens that there are display problems. Such as for example typing block info command to display my  partitions, it displays the lines with **missing characters**. Sometimes **partitions which disappear!** . After another block info,  everything   will be back in place.Same thing when i open a file with Vim.
The question is, what is the explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a hardware problem (bad cable? bad powersupply?) ??? And your question lack details: what is the precise command which is failing?

Comment: What sort of terminal interface are you using? A serial link, or some network terminal interface (SSH or Telnet)?

Comment: @IanAbbott serial, I'm using minicom .

Comment: So a serial terminal emulator, then. The problem with missing characters could be due to receiver overruns at the PC end, or bad cabling. If it is always the same characters that go missing, it could be due to incorrect parity setting.

Comment: I have had this type of issues 10 years ago with the device where serial line was actually UART <--> SPI. And the driver for SPI host controller and the chip (MAX3111 IIRC) were not so good. Problem was solved by switching to real UART which comes directly from SoC.